# Magento Migration no products after reindex

Tags: magento, indexing

We have migrated our site over to a new product server. On the initial move, everything works. After trying to do a reindex, the catalog on the frontend is empty.

All products are set to enabled, and show.
Have inventory.
I have already changed the urls in database.
I have set the admin site to ID 0 in the database tables.
The index process does not report an any errors.
Enabling / Disabling the flat catalog does not make a difference.

Really not sure where to look.

**Update**
If anyone else runs into this issue, the problem was with the customer_group table. NOT LOGGED IN group_id has to be set to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from an auto increment issue within mysql in the migration process. I get the same issue on the customer_group table in addition to the Default and admin stores being set to the wrong increment on import. I sometimes have to run this after an export/import of a database.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: If anyone runs into the this issue, Rob is correct in that the group_id is not the only issue you will run into when you go through a database migration. The above will fix the increment issues.

Comment: @Rob which tables are you talking about ?